# NHibernate: Updating database multiple times in a transaction

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Below is a simplified code of what I currently have.
I noticed that "status" remained as 0 instead of 1 or 2 when Point 1/2 throws an exception.
I initially thought Update() would do the trick, but it seems like I have to call Commit() for the changes to be in the DB.
What could be a good way for me to do this?
(showing status of 1 and 2 in DB upon returning/exception).
Any help is much appreciated.

```
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    Monitor monitor = monitorDao.Get(id);
    if (someStatus)
    {
        monitor.status = 1;    // initially monitor.status == 0 in DB
        // Point 1: some codes that might return or throw exception
    }
    else
    {
        monitor.status = 2;
        // Point 2: some codes that might return or throw exception
    }

    monitor.status = 3;
    tx.Commit();    
}
```

Comment: nhibernate maintains cache of loaded objects. All updates are done on the cache. The changes are committed when the session is flushed expicitly or when a transaction is committed or when the session gets disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to refactor you code to get the behavior you want:

```
Monitor monitor = monitorDao.Get(id);
if (someStatus)
{
    using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        monitor.status = 1;    // initially monitor.status == 0 in DB
        tx.Commit();
    }
    // Point 1: some codes that might return or throw exception
}
else
{
    using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) 
    {
        monitor.status = 2;    // initially monitor.status == 0 in DB
        tx.Commit();
    }
    // Point 2: some codes that might return or throw exception
}

 using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) 
 {
      monitor.status = 3;
      tx.Commit();
 }
```

When you had an exception, the first status update was never send to your db. By giving it a separate transaction, you first update your db by committing it. Then you do you logic which can fail. If you are doing anything at Point 1/2 which like saving to the db and what has to be in the transaction with status = 3. Then you need to refactor your code so that logic is in the second transaction.

Comment: So I really need individual transactions for each of the status update huh.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This setting is controlled by FlushMode on ISession. You should google this topic, for example this link gives some more details on FlushMode options: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-flush-mode.

> Never: changes are never flushed automatically, you must call
>   ISession.Flush() explicitly;
>
> Commit: changes are sent as soon as the
>   current ITransaction is committed, no need to call  Flush();
>
> Auto: the
>   session is flushed if a query is requested for some entity type and
>   there are dirty local entity instances, no need to call Flush(); this
>   is the default;
>
> Always: the session is flushed before any query is
>   executed, also no need to call Flush().

Comment: Thanks for the info on FlushMode! Don't think I'll change it to "Always", but it's good to know such option exists.